# Inserting PDF files into MYSQL with BLOB using VB.NET

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have been trying to figure out how to submit PDF files into a MYSQL database via my VB.NET project, so far I have only been able to figure out how to insert image files into the MYSQL but I'm not sure how to translate this code to support PDF files rather than images.
The code below shows how to browse an image and display it.

```
 Try
        Dim OFD As FileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()

        OFD.Filter = "Image File (*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif)|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.gif"

        If OFD.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
            imgpath = OFD.FileName
            PictureBox1.ImageLocation = imgpath

        End If

        OFD = Nothing

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString())
    End Try
```

The code below this shows the insertion of the image files into the MYSQL database once an image has been chosen.

```
Try
            Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
            PictureBox1.Image.Save(mstream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            arrImage = mstream.GetBuffer()
            Dim FileSize As UInt32
            FileSize = mstream.Length

            mstream.Close()
            conn.ConnectionString = Myconnection
            conn.Open()

            sql = "insert into studentsubmissions(content, submissionid, studentnumber, time, date, deadline, title, work, modulename) VALUES (@filestuff, @subid, @stunumber, @subtime, @subdate, @workdeadline, @stutitle, @stuwork, @workmodulename)"
            cmd.Connection = conn
            cmd.CommandText = sql

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@filestuff", arrImage)


            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subid", idbox.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stunumber", usernameconstant.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subtime", todaystime.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subdate", todaysdate.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workdeadline", deadlinesubmission.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stutitle", titlesubmission.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stuwork", workload.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@workmodulename", modulename.Text)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            MessageBox.Show("Created")
            cmd.Parameters.Clear()
            conn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Below this is the method of displaying a PDF file on an Adobe PDF Reader in my project which is what I eventually want replacing the first set of code in displaying the documents and making the second set of code shown to support this.

```
  Dim opf As New OpenFileDialog
    opf.Filter = "PDF File | *.pdf"

    If opf.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
        AxAcroPDF1.src = opf.FileName
        text_file.Text = opf.SafeFileName

    End If
```

Comment: I believe you need to convert the PDF to a bye array before you can store it in a database.

Comment: As you show, you need to convert an `Image` to a `Byte` array to save it to a database. That code should call `ToArray` on the `MemoryStream` rather than `GetBuffer` but the principle is the same. In this case, you need to get a `Byte` array from your PDF file. How do you usually get a `Byte` array from a file? By calling `File.ReadAllBytes`.